# Check the prediction value from txt file using BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, comparison

I want to check the correlation value from text file using bash script like this :

I have txt file that contains these kind of values : (first column is signal strength and second column is bit rate)

```
65 24
67 36
70 48
72 54
```

Then in bash script I record the current signal like this :

```
signal=`iwconfig wlan1 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}'`
```

Let's say the current signal = 67, so based on the txt file, I can predict that signal=67 has bit rate = 36.

How to compare the current signal value with the signal value inside text file hence I can get the predicted bit rate in bash script?

Comment: `awk -vs=$signal '$1==s{print $2}' correlation.txt`

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest things to do would be

```
strength=`grep ^$signal log.txt |cut -d " " -f 2`
```

but that only matches the exact signal strength.

The *^* at the before $signal indicates it only matches at the beginning of the line.